# Migration from Wildfly 10.0.0.Final to 10.1.0.Final

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm migrating a project we're developing on to the latest stable release of `Wildfly`. The project has been started with version `10.0.0.Final`, latest version is `10.1.0.Final`: thus i didn't expect issues.

But I get the following error while deploying the JMS queues the project defines (they're all deployed via the `@JMSDestinations` annotation within the `EAR`):

```
16:06:55,674 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "togather-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\""],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]",
        "jboss.connector.direct-connection-factory-activator.java:/jms/******* is missing [jboss.ra.deployer.\"jmsra.rar\"]"
    ]
```

I've tried with all the full profiles (`standalon-full`, `standalon-ha-full`) in both versions: with version 10.0.0.Final it works fine, in version `10.1.0.Final` I got the deploy issue.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you copy the standalone*.xml config from old server to new one?

Comment: @ctomc there was no need. The whole package has been built to be deployable even on a clean installatin of Wildfly, without any configuration whatsoever. I doublechecked it nonetheless trying to install in a fresh Wildfly 10.0.0.Final as well, and deploy succeeded

Comment: @ctomc i got the same issue deploying the java EE 7 Blueprint "cargotracker" as mentioned here https://github.com/javaee/cargotracker/issues/84